# iText split PdfPCell when cell is kept together

Tags: itext

I am using a table to create a semblance of what is depicted below.  The content I'm generating isn't known before hand.  The blue sections of the columns are cells that are kept together in the table and I am using `ColumnText` to display the table.  For clarification I have outlined a sample cell layout in the top right of the image.  The problem I'm running into is that when I use `setSplitLate(false)` with `setSplitRows(true)` alongside with using `keepRowsTogether(int[] rows)` the splitting doesn't work correctly.  Most of the top right section should be able to fit into the bottom left but as shown in the image it is all moved to the top of the next column.

1. Is there a way to cause the cell to split as well as keep together with it's header?  When I remove the `keepRowsTogether(int[] rows)` call the cell splitting works as expected.
2. Also, in my situation I only want it to split if there are two lines at the end of the column and two at the beginning of the next.  In other words the cell would only split if it contained 4 lines of text.  How would I go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: If you supplied a small sample class representing your implementation and producing the issue, people might be enabled to help in a non-vague manner.

Comment: I came up with an answer.  I ran into this problem at work but due to non-disclosure agreements it was best if I didn't post any code along with my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the top right column as depicted below, blue representing the rows that are kept together.

[image]

As depicted, I have a cell for the header as before but I've split up the paragraph into many different cells.  The first and last contain cells with two lines of text and the rest contain one line of text.  This way I'm guaranteed that the header will stick with at least the first two lines of the bulleted paragraph.  If the last two lines, or the last cell, end up not fitting in the column then because the cell contains two lines, I'm guaranteed that at least two lines will be carried over to the next column, if not more, depending on how many of the middle lines carry over as well.